# file delete and rename not working

Tags: java, file

Here is the code but it does not delete storedIp file and rename tempFile to storedIP. Both file exist

```
               String host=ipParsing(hostName);
               File tempFile= new File("tempFile.txt");
               File strFile = new File("StoredIp.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                String line;
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
             if(host.equals(line))
                        {
                            found=true;
                            line="";
                        }
                            bw.write(line);
                        if(!line.equals(""))
                            bw.newLine();
                  }
       bw.close();
       bufferReader.close();
               strFile.delete();
               tempFile.renameTo(new File ("StoredIP.txt"));
```

Comment: "StoredIP.txt" is not same as "StoredIp.txt"

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag It is in windows.

Comment: `tempFile.renameTo(strFile)` is unproblematic too.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of either swing or java-ee to this question.  Those tags removed, file tag added.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a call to [File.delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) does not necessary delete the file.
As the JavaDoc says: be sure to check the return value.

Ignoring this (like you did) is a common source of errors.

Comment: How would one debug the issue if the return value turned out to be false? In my case, when my files weren't being deleted, it was because all of the library calls I was using did not close their files after they were done with it! It looks like at least the files are being closed here. But I'm assuming OP did not post the complete code so there's a try/catch somewhere and that message should explain what's going on.

Comment: If a file is not deleted, the usual suspect is an open handle somewhere. I would start by using a tool which shows me the process that holds that handle.

Answer (score 1):

One occasion where this delete/renameTo easily goes awry, is when *the files are in use*. A solution seen consists of using an additional lock file. Too complicated for such a simple thing.

Using an *embedded database*, like java's own Derby, which is not that difficult. The database needs no extra provision. There are good tutorials with simple example code.